# How to make the same font of the exported PDF file and CR designer in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, pdf-generation

My report in exported PDF version and in CR designer are not the same. The font in the PDF looks smaller than in the designer and I don't know why. Of course, that makes a big problem for me, because I am getting unused "white space". The problem is shown in the image below:

[image]

I am using SAP Crystal Reports 2013. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this, I needed to create a registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\Export\PDF\ForceLargerFonts

And then to set: ForceLargerFonts to the value dword: 00000001

And it works fine now.

Comment: Having the same issue, I don't understand your solution though - do I need to change this on the server side or dev PC? Does it change the designer or the end product, exported PDF?

Comment: @Uporabnik003 I did this on my dev machine. It changes the end product, you don't see changes in the designer.

Comment: This also solved a problem where the font was being enlarged on an exported pdf which was leading to truncation of important text. After setting this same value the MICRE13 font rendered the proper size.